# On Ubuntu Server 12.04, how do I make a shell script that replaces underscores with spaces recursively?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server, scripts

So far I have:

```
for file in *\_*
do file_clean="${file//_/ }"
mv --verbose "$file" "$file_clean"
done
```

However, it only renames files in the root directory of the folder. How do I make it rename the files with underscores to spaces recursively on all of the files and folders within that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the find command (see man find).  That will go through all subdirectories and can run a command file on each file name using the -exec {} option.

Comment: Thanks.  I used "find /this/ismydirectory/ -depth -name "*_*" -execdir rename 's/_/ /g' "{}" \;" to rename my directories.  Seems to be working perfectly.